# what could be the effects of lack of copyright and Patent protections on a country's economy?

Tags: law

would it hinder or encourage growth ? since without incentives to profit from discoveries and creativity there wouldn't be newer innovations but at the same time could ease of access to copyright help innovation by allowing early access to such knowledge for potential innovators who can build upon the work of the original inventors ?